# Biblatex: cite command to create numeric citation without parentheses?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a large table which gives a literature overview and contains only citations in its cells.

I'm using biblatex with a numeric format, so sources are normally cited as

- [33],
- [35-37, 49]
- [123, S. 54f] etc.

The parentheses need a lot of space (the table has many columns), so I'd like to remove them (only) in this table:
Is there a `\cite` command which only gives the numeric key (and the pages) without parenthesis like

- 33
- 35-37, 49
- 123, S. 54f

**Note**: I need this modification without [] *only in this one table*, not in the rest of the document!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:** Changed the answer according to the comment, that Martin is using `numeric-comp`

You can create a new cite command which based on the code of `numeric-comp.cbx`

The default setting is:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

So you create:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\tabcite}%[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

and now use `\tabcite{<key>}`

Here is a minimal example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={Vorname Name},
title ={The Title},
year={2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\tabcite}%[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}\qquad\tabcite{test}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I use biblatex v1.6.

[image]

Comment: thank you! Where do I have to put the \DeclareCite command? I put in in my preamble and got an error message "Bibliography macro 'cite' undefined"

Comment: @Martin: The preamble is correct. I will add a minimal example.

Comment: Thank you for the minimal example! (It works for me, but:) I'm using the style *`numeric-comp`* and then I get the above error message. Would that also work with your installation? (I still have biblatex 1.4, must see how I can upgrade to 1.6, if that should be the reason for my problem)

Comment: @Martin: I edited my post. Why do you use `biblatex` v1.4? You can update the package with your package manager as usual.

Comment: My package manager TeX Live Utiliy (MacOS X) refuses to update any packages as I still have TeXLive 2010 on my machine. It seems that I'll have to install TeXLive 2011, which I will do asap. Thanks for the change of your MWE.

Comment: I tried the new MWE, but it does not work either. So it seems to be because of my old version of biblatex?! I'll try to update and try again later.

Answer (score 8):

I'd simply redefine `\mkbibbrackets` to do nothing inside the group created by the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\mkbibbrackets}[1]{#1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\autocite[99]{A01}
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

Some text \autocite[99]{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put this before the table:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

and then after the table, put back the normal numeric style definition:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```