# Getting really bare numeric citations in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I've finally given in and gone over to biblatex, at least for my thesis.  I'm using a superscripted numeric reference style, and that works nicely.  However it's sometimes useful to be able to say something like "Data taken from reference 1".  If I use `cite{some_ref}`, I get "...from reference [1]".  This is by design according to the manual, but I had [a nice way of doing this in bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126914/28808) -- so how can I replicate this?

Also (I suspect the answer will be related) my bibliography is listed with the citation numbers in square brackets.

I'm starting to wish I'd stuck with bibtex - the benefits of using biblatex seem tiny compared to the hassle of switching mid document.

Comment: Don't lose your faith in `biblatex`. Admittedly, its documentation is quite full-on and hard to fathom at times; but I dare say it is second-to-none when it comes to customising the output to fit your needs, and often these solutions turn out to be quite elegant and short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might like to try

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}
```

In your preamble.

The first two commands make sure no brackets are around the numbers in the bibliography. While the second block strips brackets from the `\cite{}` (and its multicite version `\cites{}`; `\parencite{}` still has brackets, though).

```
\documentclass[english]{article}  
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\begin{document}
  See \cite{wilde} as noted before\supercite{wilde}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

---

Since the OP seems to use `numeric-comp`, the fix for that is

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

instead of the redefinition of `\cite` above.

For `numeric-verb` it's

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: You might like to try `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1\adddot}
` to get "1. Oscar Wilde ..." in the bibliography.

Comment: Many, many thanks for all of this.  For reference, when using `numeric-comp`, at least (and possibly without), the `DeclareCiteCommand` needs to be more like the one given at [this answer] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25967/28808) (`cite`->`cite:comp` suppresses an error, but results in no output for the bare citations)

Comment: Thanks again - I was on `numeric` when I asked, after a scattergun debug process, but shouldn't have been.