# Parentheses around citations with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

From [biblatex's documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), p. 94: `\cite` and `\Cite` *print the citation without any additions such as parentheses.*

Then why does the following code print "[1]."?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{A01}.
\end{document}
```

([Biblatex: cite command to create numeric citation without parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25962/biblatex-cite-command-to-create-numeric-citation-without-parentheses) provides a solution, but I'm looking for the reason of this behaviour. Is it misconfiguration?)

Comment: with numeric citation styles the destinction between \cite and \parencite doesn't make much sense, so \cite does "the normal thing", which means brackets.

Comment: "*These are the bare citation commands. They print the citation without any additions such as parentheses. **The numeric and alphabetic styles still wrap the label in square brackets since the reference may be ambiguous otherwise**.*"

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I was actually using the numeric style..

Comment: Numeric is the default (like plain style for bibtex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style is `numeric`, and to quote a little bit more from the manual:

> These are the bare citation commands. They print the citation without any additions such as parentheses. **The `numeric` and `alphabetic` styles still wrap the label in square brackets since the reference may be ambiguous otherwise**

(Emphasis mine.)

Hence, that output is to expected, and by design.