BiblaTex squarebrackets
How to remove square brackets in cite command? Here is an example of problem

Here is the bibliography
@online{Olimpiadaru,
    title     = {Olimpiada.ru, функциональные уравнения},
    url       = {https://olympiads.mccme.ru/lktg/2006/3/3-3ru.pdf},
    keywords  = {Olimpiada.ru}
}

Here is my code in preamble
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, usenames, dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm, mathtools}
% Гиперссылки
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=green,
    urlcolor=Red,
}

% Цвета
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{Библиография/func_eq.bib} %Import the bibliography file

% Окружение для задачи --- условие
% =====================================
\newcounter{mytask}[section]
\newenvironment{task}[4][]{\par\smallskip
\refstepcounter{mytask}
    \ifx&#1&
        \smallskip\noindent{\bfseries\themytask.} #2
    \else
        \smallskip\noindent{\bfseries\themytask}{\bfseries.}  (\emph{#1}) #2
 \fi
 }{
 \par\smallskip
}
% ====================================

And here is the part of code with problem
\begin{document}
\begin{task}[\cite{Olimpiadaru}]
    {Существует ли такая непрерывная функция $f : \R \to \R$, что при всех $x \in \R$, $f(f(x))=x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}$?}
    {}
    {Нет}
\end{task}
\printbibliography %Prints bibliography

\end{document}

I use the \cite command for links to source, but this produces square brackets too. Please help

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I will add more information, thanks for correcting me!

Here is a quick hack to remove the square backets: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25982/36296

THANKS A LOT!!!

Yeah, you are right, but i haven't found this question

welcome! the search function sucks, so finding questions is hard. even questions you know are there is hard. note that PLK is biblatex's author, so that solution may be best. on the other hand, that question is slightly different from yours.
